# Realtime Updates no longer sends notifications for user with disabled apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, real-time-updates

We use the Realtime Updates provided by facebook to keep our app up to date. Up until a few days ago every thing worked perfectly and we recieved notofications for every new post, comment etc on the pages wall.
A few days ago this changed. If a user has disabled all apps in hie personal settings we no longer recieve notifications for his comments or posts.
Is this working as intented? Has Facebook changed the behavior? Or is this a bug and will be fixed?

Thanks

Comment: If the user has disabled the app, why should you still get his updates?

Comment: Thats part of my question. Up until monday last week or so we recieved the notifications for these posts and comments. Then they stoped. Is it now working as intented and it was a bug before or is it now a bug?